Issue with Framing ASP.NET Web Forms Application from Another IP – 403 Forbidden on AJAX Calls
I have an ASP.NET Web Forms application and this is my billing page
http://192.168.3.38/eTriageDynamicNZ-v2/casedetailbilling.aspx?PatientID=508217&Source=F&UserName=ADMIN&isEditable=0.
On the billing page of this application, I am creating an authSessionID and setting user context as follows:
if (dsTemp.Tables["User"].Rows.Count > 0)
{
    Users objUsers = new Users();
    objUsers.UserID = int.Parse(dsTemp.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString());
    objUsers.UserName = userName;
    objUsers.firstName = dsTemp.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["ForeName"].ToString();
    objUsers.middleName = dsTemp.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["MiddleName"].ToString();
    objUsers.lastName = dsTemp.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["SurName"].ToString();
    objUsers.Priviliges = dsTemp.Tables["Roles"].Rows[0]["PrivilegeID"].ToString();
    objUsers.StaffID = int.Parse(dsTemp.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["StaffID"].ToString());
    objUsers.Hospitals = dsTemp.Tables["User"].Rows[0]["Hospital"].ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["UserContext"] = objUsers;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["CSRF"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["jwt"] = JwtTokenHanlder.GenerateAdminToken("userName");

    // authSessionID added
    string authSessionID = JwtHandlerForTriage.GenerateToken(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);
    HttpContext.Current.Session["authSessionID"] = authSessionID;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("authSessionID", authSessionID));
}

However, when this URL is framed within another application, the following issues arise:
When the frame is from the same IP address (i.e., 192.168.3.38), everything works fine.
When trying to access the application from another IP (e.g., 192.168.3.160), a 403 Forbidden error occurs on two AJAX calls. This issue only happens when the application is framed.


<add name="content-security-policy" value="form-action 'self'; object-src 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self' http://192.168.3.38 http://192.168.3.160 http://192.168.3.38:81 http://192.168.3.188:81; img-src 'self' data:; base-uri 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />

I have configured the Content-Security-Policy header in the web.config to allow framing from specific IP addresses:
